# How extract all part of string after Date format

Tags: r

I have this string :

```
str1 <- "rwxrwxr-x   3 1EX4-sniRE bf1EX4        641 2019-01-17 18:35 /hdfs/data/adhoc/RE/34/1EX4/InterfacePublique/Prepublication-PUB_1EGCP-20070101"
```

And I need to select all part of string from 2019-01-17

So As final result I should get:

```
2019-01-17 18:35 /hdfs/data/adhoc/RE/34/1EX4/InterfacePublique/Prepublication-PUB_1EGCP-20070101"
```

I tried using `str_extract_all` function But it doesn't give the needed result.

Answer (score 2):

One option in base R:

```
sub("^.*(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})", "\\1", str1)
[1] "2019-01-17 18:35 /hdfs/data/adhoc/RE/34/1EX4/InterfacePublique/Prepublication-PUB_1EGCP-20070101"
```

Almost the same logic with `stringr`:

```
stringr::str_extract(str1, "\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}.+")
```